# Base class destructor is not virtual and child class destructor is virtual, program crash

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

Why does the following program crash? I have a base class whose destructor is not virtual but the child class destructor is virtual:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  Base() {
    std::cout << "Base::Base CTOR " << std::endl;
  }
  ~Base() {
    std::cout << "Base::Base DTOR " << std::endl;
  }
};

class Child : public Base {
public:
  Child(){
    std::cout << "Child::Child CTOR " << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~Child() {
    std::cout << "Child::Child DTOR " << std::endl;
  }

};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  Base *ptr = new Child;
  delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: Base class destructor should be `virtual`

Comment: you should make your base class destructor virtual, see this link for more details http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

Comment: did it crash *after* or writing "Base::Base DTOR " or did it never write this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are observing is called "undefined behavior". Make `Base`'s dtor virtual if you want do call delete on `Child` instance through `Base` pointer.

From the 2003 standard, 5.3.5/3:

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a
>   base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall
>   have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Because he is lying to the compiler about the memory he wants freed.

Comment: memory freed doesn't depend on the destructor called directly (well, it could if there're some memory resources held by `Child`). Actually, I was looking for exact statement, what constitutes to this being UB, ideally it would be a reference to the standard.

Answer (score 5):

You have undefined behavior because the static type of the pointer operand to delete does not match the dynamic type of the object that it points to and you don't meet the requirements for the exception to this rule that allows passing a pointer to a base class to the object being deleted because this exception requires the *base* class to have a virtual destructor.

Any behaviour is possible including the code working "as expected" or a crash.

Comment: You could consider rephrasing a bit, because the word 'exception' confused me (I thought about `C++` exceptions). Actually, I understood your answer only after reading @wilx's quote from the standard.

Comment: @unkulunkulu: I've considered rephrasing but right now I can't think of a better word than 'exception' to describe an exception to a rule.

Comment: But you can rephrase not only by replacing this work, you could add another sentence, like 'you can't do that, but there's an exception, but in your case, you dont't meet the requirements' or something :D

Comment: @CharlesBailey: There is no such an exception: ivoking a method from a base pointer will always call the base method if that method is not virtual. And delete invokes the destructor that is itself a method. I don't see any exceptional behavior here: the wrong function had been invoked producing an unexpected result.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: I'm talking about the exception to the rule that the static type of the pointer that you pass to `delete` must match the dynamic type of the object being deleted. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The point is there is no such "rule" (or better: there is no need for it) `delete p` behave exactly like `p->method()` where method is the d-tor. What does p->method invoke if *method* is virtual or not? The same is `delete p`.

The UB depends from the fact that "partial destruction" cannot be supported. But the rule behind the `virtual` keyword is the same.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Destructors aren't usually called through a virtual function mechanism because they aren't usually called explicitly; they are called because an object is being destroyed, either directly or because they are a member or base of an object which itself is being destroyed. There very much is a rule that if the operand to `delete` is a pointer to a base class sub-object of a more derived object then the base class must have a virtual destructor. This is listed in the standard under the rules for `delete` expressions (5.3.5 [expr.delete]).

Comment: @CharlesBailey: 5.3.5 is about the UB of deleting through a base via non virtual dtor, but THAT's NOT AN EXCEPTION to the general rule about invocation of member thorugh pointers.

Your distinction between explicit invocation or invocation via delete is pointless. the expression `delete p` seek for what destructor to call following the exact same rule `p->method`. There is nothing "exceptional" in that.

spec. 5.3.5 is not an exception, it's just the description on what happens **after** missing to destroy part of an object (UB).

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: I gave the simple rule for an operand to delete. The static type of the pointer must match the dynamic type of the object being deleted. The exception to this rule is that you are also allowed to pass a pointer to a base class of a more derived object provided that the base class type has a virtual function. This is an informal expression of (a subset of) the requirements specified for delete expressions in 5.3.5. If you meet these requirements then the most derived object will be destroyed with destructors being called from the top down.

Comment: This is quite different to normal virtual functions where an overriding function _replaces_ the overridden with the overridden function only being called if there is an explicit call to the base class version in the overridden version.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this example helps you get the point:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
public:
 Base() {
    std::cout << "Base::Base CTOR " << std::endl;
 }
 ~Base() {
   std::cout << "Base::Base DTOR " << std::endl;
 }
private:
protected:
};

class Child : public Base {
 public:
 Child(){
std::cout << "Child::Child CTOR " << std::endl;
  }
  ~Child(){
std::cout << "Child::Child DTOR " << std::endl;
 }
  private:
 protected:
 };
  class gChild : public Child {
   public:
   gChild(){
    std::cout << "Child::Child gCTOR " << std::endl;
   }
  ~gChild(){
    std::cout << "Child::Child gDTOR " << std::endl;
  }
private:
protected:
};
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    Base *ptr = new gChild;
 delete ptr;
}
```

if virtual ~Base() ,then all destructors' print gets printed.

if virtual ~child() or virtual ~gChild(),only base destructor gets printed.

It's because the destructors executes in opposite direction.and here behaviour is undefined.You must define the base destructor virtual to get the expected result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void nonvirtualmethod()
    { std::cout << "Base nonvirtualmethod" << std::endl; }
    virtual void virtualmethod()
    { std::cout << "Base virtualmethod" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void nonvirtualmethod()
    { std::cout << "Derived nonvirtualmethod" << std::endl; }
    virtual void virtualmethod()
    { std::cout << "Derived virtualmethod" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Derived* pd = &d;
    Base* pb = &d;    //< NOTE: both pd and pb point to the same object

    pd->nonvirtualmethod();
    pb->nonvirtualmethod();
    pd->virtualmethod();
    pb->virtualmethod();
}
```

I gives you the following output:

```
Derived nonvirtualmethod
Base nonvirtualmethod
Derived virtualmethod
Derived virtualmethod  //< invoked by a Base*
```

This is because there is a difference between the static type of the `pb` pointer (`Base*`)
and the dynamic type it points to (`Derived`).
The difference between virtual and plain methods is that non-virtual methods follow the the static type mapping (so a `Base` pointer invokes `Base::`methods), while virtual methods follow the chain of the runtime types, hence if a `Base*` points to a `Derived`, the `Derived` method will be called.

Destructors, in this sense, are nothing special: if it is not virtual, a `Base` pointer will not invoke the `Derived` one, hence you are left with an half-destroyed object, that is given back to the memory store.

The reason why this is UB (and not simply denied), is because the "memory store" is not managed by the language itself, but from the platform the program is hosted in: the crash most likely depends on the fact that the missing of the `Derived` part (still alive) will result in the operating system trying free a block of memory with a wrong starting address.